# unintended effects from batch cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a batch query that that I am executing in batches passing an `$attribs` parameter.

`$attribs` is:

```
[{
  attribs: [{row_attribs:{attrKey:"attrValue"}}],
  match_crit:[ {matchKey:"matchVal"}]
}]
```

Query:

```
UNWIND $attribs AS attrib_dict
UNWIND attrib_dict.attribs as attrib_row
UNWIND attrib_dict.match_crit as match_row
CREATE (src:{src_ent})
SET src += attrib_row.row_attribs
WITH src, match_row
MATCH (to:Article} {{name:match_row.matchKey})
CREATE (src)-[:REL]->(to)
```

I am writing in batches of 250 yet on each batch something like 40k nodes are being created (very many duplicates causing this large number). How could this be? Could this be because I have multiple UNWIND clauses in my query? I assume something is getting funky with how I am handling the params within my query but don't want to start hacking away on my code without a purpose or understanding.

NB I would normally write in much larger batches (appx 5k nodes) but was encountering out of memory errors and I am guessing this explosion of node creation is the reason for that error.

Comment: Alright, I think since I am chaining UNWINDS I am actually creating a cartesian product which is creating my problem of the explosion of duplicate nodes. I am going to refactor to chop this into two queries. Will post my solution if/when I get it working :)

Comment: Is that `$attribs` parameter what you are actually using? If so, all your `UNWIND`s should only cause one resulting row, and it would seem that it is your `MATCH` clause that is generating multiple rows.